# Are Simhadri Appanna & Narasimha swamy same?

Tags: vishnu, narasimha

Are Simhadri Appanna & Narasimha same gods or different?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narasimha

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Both are same.

Appa means "father" in telugu. Word "Appa" is added as Narasimha Swamy is father to all. So, He is also called as "Appanna" .

Chaganti Koteswara Rao, well known scholar in Telugu states,  explains the meaning of word Appa and reason for adding it in [this video](https://youtu.be/tA-RT6YCQbw?t=1460) (in telugu).

Comment: I thought appa was a non-telugu word for father?

Comment: @moonstar2001 Appa is Telugu word. You can check [here](http://andhrabharati.com/dictionary/index.php).